# What's the meaning of std::enable_if_t = 0

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I was reading [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), and noticed the following.

```
template <typename Integer,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value, int> = 0
>
T(Integer) : m_type(int_t) {}
```

Since std::enable_if_t is a type, and it can be evaluated to `int` or `void` for this case, so the above code can be evaluated to

```
template <typename Integer,
          int = 0
>
T(Integer) : m_type(int_t) {}
```

or

```
template <typename Integer,
          void = 0
>
T(Integer) : m_type(int_t) {}
```

I can't understand `int = 0` or `void = 0`, would someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Since `std::enable_if_t` is a type, and it can be evaluated to `int` or `void` for this case, so the above code can be evaluated to ...

This is not correct.  With `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value, int>` the only type `std::enable_if_t` can be is `int`.  If `std::is_integral<Integer>::value` is not true, then there is no member at all and the template instantiation is thrown out.  That means it only resolves to

```
template <typename Integer,
          int = 0
>
T(Integer) : m_type(int_t) {}
```

where `int = 0` is just an unnamed non-type template parameter with the value of `0`.

The reason we do `= 0` is so that it has a default value and we don't need to pass a value to it when declaring a object of this type.  Without it you would not be able to use this constructor at all as there is no way to specify the template parameters of a constructor.  Even if this wasn't a constructor, you would still want to use a default value so the user does not need to pass a unneeded value to that unnamed and unused template parmater.